# '401 Unauthorised' when calling a url with Net.WebClient

Tags: vb.net, url, authentication, webclient

In my app I'm making a call to an API.

I start by building the URL...

```
Dim url As String = "http://" & Home.sn_username & ":" & Home.sn_password & "@" & Home.sn_ip & "/command.htm?number=" & phonenumber
url = Replace(url, Chr(13), "")
```

I want to make sure the URL its attempting to call is correct, so i've dumped it to the console...

```
Console.WriteLine("DIALING: " & url)
```

The URL is spot on, so finally I call the URL with Net.Webclient...

```
Dim client As New Net.WebClient
client.DownloadString(url)
```

This does not work. 
An exception is thrown and I get a 401 Unauthorised error.

Am i doing something wrong?
The final URL is like this:

http://username:passwrd@domainame.com/command.htm?Number=01611234565

If i take that and paste it directly into my browser it works fine! (its for an IP phone API... my desk phone dials the number!).

Do i need to look at a different way of supplying the credentials or something?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you behind a firewall?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your authentication credentials directly to the WebClient instead of prepending them before the url before executing.

```
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Home.sn_username, Home.sn_password)
```

Comment: Thanks Fatih, That semi worked in that it clearly makes the API call now, but weirdly it still gives me an exception with a 401 error. Strange. I could just surpress the error, but i'd like to know whats causing it if possible! :)

Comment: @John Well I am not sure, could you have forgotten to omit the authentication part from the URL?

Comment: Sadly not, checked and double checked it. god knows :(